# Can I remove Compiz and still run Gnome desktop?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, gnome-classic

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto a fairly old desktop machine. I installed Gnome desktop without problem. Nothing else was installed other than g++ and Eclipse.

I don't know what Compiz is, but I keep getting Compiz crash reports at login now (with gnome classic option).

It doesn't seem critical and doesn't effect the running of the machine, at least in an obvious way.

The errors seemed to start happening after installing the gnome desktop. Can I ignore this crash report or is it something to be worried about?  Can I remove Compiz or is it crucial to Ubuntu running?

Comment: I don't think the question itself should be closed as an off-topic/bug report case -- it only uses the buggy behavior as context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiz is a compositing window manager for the X Window System, using 3D graphics hardware to create fast compositing desktop effects for window management.

It's not crucial to have for Ubuntu to run if you plan on using gnome-classic.